# WCF Duplex netTcp Connections hangs sometimes for about 4 seconds

Tags: wpf, wcf, tcp

I have a very strange behavior using a WCF duplex channel with a netTcpBinding.
The WCF callback hangs sometimes (every 1 - 10 minutes) for about 4-5 seconds and I have no Idea why. This does not happen if I use a NetNamedPipeBinding instead.

Setup WCF Service:

- WCF Service is hosted by a WindowsService
- duplex channel uses a NetTcp Binding
- Message is send approx. 20 times pre second with a date size of about 100 kB (I have also tried it with a message size of 2 MB and it looks like the hang occures a little bit more often)
- More than one client can connect to the service. The service is marked with the attribute [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
- for every client a seperate thred is started for doing the callbacks

AccessContract

- Callback functions are void functions and marked with the attribute [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]

Setup WCF Client

- WPF Application
- Opens the Channel in a worker-thread (!= Main-Thread) --> Callbacks are also called in this thread
- the WCF client runs on the same machine as the service

If have already done following analyses

- wcf service trace log: The call is send from the service to the client but is executed at the client 5 seconds late
- If more than one client is connected to the service, the hang occurs more often (but mostly only one client hangs at one time)
- I have checked the .NET GC if he is busy during the hang --> negativ
- I have also checked if there is other network traffic --> negativ

For me it looks like a netTcp problem but I have no Idea what's the reason and how I can analyse it or avoid the problem. I do not want to use pipes as the client should also run on other machines.

**Update**:

I can see the described problem only, if the WCF service and the client are running on the same computer. If the client runs on another computer, everything works fine (even if I start several clients on other computers).

Comment: Have you tried increasing the max number of TCP connections to greater than the default 10? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731343(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have increased the value with no effect. But I think this can not be the reason as the described problem appears also if only one client is connected (and the duplex channel is opend once and then stays open).

Comment: I have asked the questions also here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/64ace413-fbf4-460a-8553-afecb9c9f20b/wcf-duplex-nettcp-connections-hangs-sometimes-for-about-4-seconds?forum=wcf